# Dungeon with puzzle traps that force players to act as a team

Tags: dnd-5e, traps, dungeon, puzzle

I just started recently to DM a campaign (first campaign ever as DM), and I want to create a Dungeon with puzzle traps based on the concept of teamwork (much like that one SAW movie), and I have several ideas but don't know very well how to implement them. For example, a long narrow corridor of pressure plates that make spikes come from the walls impaling the individual that traverse it, the catch? if the plates are all being pressed down at the same time (except for the first and last one) the spikes wont activate.

In the end what I would like are a set of traps of the sort that when dealt with as a team end up being harmless or the damage each one receives is notably less that if each one tried their hand on their own against the dungeon traps.

Any ideas about traps of this kind (traps themselves or ways to correctly implement them) and also ways of foreshadowing the solution of the puzzle would be extremely appreciated, as well as any insight on the matter (I've looked for traps like this but I couldn't find any). Thanks again and have a good day.

Comment: Hello Aaron and welcome to RPG.stackexchange! Kindly take the [tour] and enjoy your stay. While I think this is a cool idea, our site doesn't accommodate idea generation questions well. You should maybe look up a forum from our [curated list of forums](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5449/ive-been-told-my-question-is-better-suited-to-a-forum-but-where-should-i-go) to ask this question on.

Comment: @kviiri oh OK, thanks. should I take the question down?

Comment: There's no particular need, it'll be closed over time automatically (it's not a punishment or anything, just clean-up). I'd be happy to help you brainstorm on [chat] though, sadly it just requires 20 reputation to join.

Comment: @AaronParrilla XGtE has a section on complex traps which might give you inspiration. In all other cases you are better of asking in a forum. Good luck!

Comment: @LiamMorris Do not answer in comments, We can give them rep to enter chat and direct them to other resources.